# How do you set up tab autocompletion (for directories) in a Ruby CLI program?

Tags: ruby, bash, readline, command-line-interface, thor

**Background on what I'm trying to do:**

I've been teaching myself `Ruby`, and as a test project I'm creating a `.csv` converter. It's working well over all, but what I'm stuck on is allowing the user to easily select the file to be imported. Right now I prompt for the file path with the following code:

```rb
def find_original_path
  puts "\nWhere is the file that you would like to convert?"
  print ">> "
  @original_path = gets.chomp
  if File.exists?(@original_path)
    # Verify that file is a .csv
    check_original_type()
  else
    puts "\nSorry, that file doesn't seem to exist."
    # Ask for a new path to file
    find_original_path()
  end
end
```

**What I'd like to do:**

So this works, but it requires that the user know the *exact* path to their `.csv`. What I'd prefer is to allow the user to use `bash` style auto-completion to find their file. Typing `~/` should start off at the user's home directory, and then hitting `tab` twice should list all available folders/files and so on.

**What I've found:**

`Readline`: My understanding is that this module only works for pre-set lists.

`Thor`: Awesome module, but seems to only work for providing deep `argument` functionality (e.g. `git` commands).

`Shoes (and variants)`: Apparently `green_shoes` in particular has an easy way of doing this, but I'm not yet looking to put a `GUI` on this tool.

`Ruby's Std-lib`: I've gone through `FileUtils`, `File`, `IO`, etc...

`Backticks` and `Open4`: Makes sense for commands like `ls`, but not sure about directories.

**In Sum:**

Haven't found an answer that stood out to me in any of these. I feel like the answer to my problem is either more complex than I realized, or all of my reading has me missing something that's right under my nose. I'm hoping it's the latter, though please be gentle if it's *really* blindingly obvious :D

Any advice?

Comment: could you please elaborate on the thor module auto-completion usage? what do you mean by deep argument?